# When I go routes forth-and-back are page states preserved?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state, flutter-routes

Is a. page widget; b. its state recreated anew or remains the same as it was on the previous show of the same page by:

1. `Navigator.pushNamed()`
2. `Navigator.pop()`?

Answer (score 0):

The state of a previous widget is preserved after a push from the navigator.
The gestures are just ignored for the current widget while a new one is pushed into frame.

[flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamed.html)

Comment: Please rewrite in more clear words. "The widget of a previous state is preserved..." What do you mean by "widget of state"? Please be clear about both `pushNamed` and `pop`. It is unclear if your wording applies to both. In short: reword clearly, please.

Comment: I meant a state of a widget. my bad mate

Comment: But will a widget have the same state if: `Navigator.pushNamed("/a", xxx); Navigator.pushNamed("/b", yyy); Navigator.pushNamed("/a", zzz);`

Comment: No. The widget is still kept in the stack. But pushing the same widget will only create another instance with a new state. You can pop to go back to the previous widget.